# Make Chrome notifications last longer

Tags: google-chrome

i am a complete noob in coding, i have a question on how to make chrome's notifications stay until i dismiss them like youtube does. I have already seen the answers to the question, but i really don't understand how to do it. Hope you can support my noobiness and make a quick tutorial on how i can do it, i would appreciate it. it's crucial for me i have to do this but i don't know how to code in chrome and developer stuff i read many blogs and posts but still can't understand. Any help is highly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a notification persist until dismissed with `requireInteraction` flag:

- Indicates that the notification should remain visible on screen until the user activates or dismisses the notification. This defaults to false.

Comment: Thank you Liam ~ but my problem is i dont understand what is the requireInteraction flag or how to get to it ㅠㅠ excuse my noobness

Comment: @RealRacer This should help: http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2012/07/all-about-chrome-flags.html